# Problem with for loops over user-defined structures

Tags: julia

I have structures defined as:

```
struct CLocation{T<:Real}
  x::Array{T,1}
  y::Array{T,1}
  z::Array{T,1}
end

struct CSize{T<:Real}
  x::Array{T,1}
  y::Array{T,1}
  z::Array{T,1}
end

struct FLocation{T<:Real}
  x::Array{T,1}
  y::Array{T,1}
  z::Array{T,1}
end

struct MStructure
  dimension::Real
  dims::Array{Int,1}
  csize::CSize
  ccenters::CLocation
  fcenters::FLocation
  corner::Array{Int,1}
  edge::Array{Int,1}
end

struct CValue # {T<:Real}
  domain::MStructure
  value::Union{Array{<:Real}, DenseArray{Bool}} #Union{Array{T}, BitArray{}}
end
```

With operators for these structures:

```
for f in [:+, :-, :*, :/, :^, :(==), :>, :(>=), :<, :(<=)]
  @eval function $f(a::CValue, b::CValue)
      return CValue(a.domain, $f.(a.value, b.value))
  end
end

for f in [:+, :-, :*, :/, :^, :(==), :>, :(>=), :<, :(<=)]
  @eval function $f(a::CValue, b::Real)
      return CValue(a.domain, $f.(a.value, b))
  end
end

for f in [:+, :-, :*, :/, :^, :(==), :>, :(>=), :<, :(<=)]
  @eval function $f(a::Real, b::CValue)
      return CValue(b.domain, $f.(a, b.value))
  end
end
```

I have two types of variables: `val::Cvalue` and `vec::Vector{Cvalue}(undef,N)`

I am trying to loop over them to perform summations, and I have success when implemeting:

```
function calc_sum(N,vec,val)
    for i in 1:N
        val = val + vec[i]
    end
    return val
end
```

Where I have initialized `val` as 0

Is there a more succinct way to perform this loop? Preferably in the format of: `val = [val + vec[i] for i in 1:N]`

which returns a vector of type `Cvalue`, when my intention is that val is simply of type `Cvalue`

I have tried `val = (val + vec[i] for i in 1:N)` with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Julia 1.6 and later you can use `sum(vec; init = val)`.
In older versions you can use `reduce(+, vec; init = val)` or `foldl(+, vec; init = val)` if `+` is non associative.

If you want to keep enumeration, then you can do something like `foldl((acc, i) -> vec[i] + acc, 1:length(vec); init = val)` or equivalently

```
foldl(1:length(vec); init = val) do acc, i
  acc + vec[i]
end
```